# Is there of a way to pass a list of strings as comma separated strings to a function's args in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, args

I want to take strings from the user without any limit and pass it into a function as different parameters for e.g

```
user_input = "Hello World! It is a beautiful day."
```

I want to pass this string split by spaces as parameters into a function i.e

```
func("Hello", "World!", "It", "is", "a", "beautiful", "day.")
```

And I cannot pass a list or tuple, it has to be multiple strings. I am new to python, sorry if the solution is very simple

Comment: Sure, you can do that. Check `*args`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `*args` (and `**kwargs` if needed) for this. ([More details here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3394835/use-of-args-and-kwargs))

```
def func(*args):
    for s in args:
        print(s)
```

Then in your call you can use `*` to unpack the result of `split` into individual arguments. (More about [extended iterable unpacking](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/))

```
>>> user_input = "Hello World! It is a beautiful day."
>>> func(*user_input.split())
Hello
World!
It
is
a
beautiful
day.
```

Comment: Will this work even if function has multiple different arguments instead of *args? i.e 
func(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4): #code
I know it will throw an error if the user passes more arguments than parameters

Comment: Yes it will, the important part is `*user_input.split()` notice the `*` in front.